# Access rights with Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd like to be able to create a View in one database (let's call this Database A) that is comprised of selected fields from a particular table in another database (Database B). However, I'd like this view to be accessible by a user that has read/write rights to Database A, but no rights to Database B directly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-database ownership chaining (`ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET DB_CHAINING ON`) should work for this situation.